# Troubles installing Matplotlib with pip (python 3.10 windows 11)

Tags: python, matplotlib, cmd, pip, jupyter

Im having a lot of difficulty installing matplotlib for **python 3.10.0** on my *new* **windows 11** machine. I will explain from the top down

In my VScode jupyter file I try to run the folowing code cell

```
import matplotlib
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

I hop over to my cmd and run the folowing lines:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

> Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\robbe\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages

```
pip install wheel
```

> Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\users\robbe\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages

```
pip install matplotlib
```

> Collecting matplotlib
> Using cached matplotlib-3.4.3.tar.gz (37.9 MB)
> Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
> all these requirements were satisfies
> Building wheels for collected packages: matplotlib
> Building wheel for matplotlib (setup.py) ... error

and now I get a huge error

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'C:\Users\robbe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\robbe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i7jkrq6p\matplotlib_45378a3fc28d4ce6bb53fd38cb01c06b\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\robbe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i7jkrq6p\matplotlib_45378a3fc28d4ce6bb53fd38cb01c06b\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\robbe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-_bz0a7px'
> cwd: C:\Users\robbe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i7jkrq6p\matplotlib_45378a3fc28d4ce6bb53fd38cb01c06b
> Complete output (553 lines):

folowed by another error

> ERROR: Failed building wheel for matplotlib
> Running setup.py clean for matplotlib
> Failed to build matplotlib
> Installing collected packages: matplotlib
> Running setup.py install for matplotlib ... error

Can someone help explain to me whats wrong here? I've tried almost every solution I could find on here (such as specifying a differet matplotlib build to install or running the line pip install --upgrade matplotlib) but I can't get it fixed

:( I just want to make some graphs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matplotlib+python-3.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry you guys, I've used this line

```
pip install matplotlib==3.5.0rc1
```

And this versions of matplotlib did work!!!! :)

Comment: If you found your own answer to this, you can mark this post as your selected answer ;)